# Is Spring Integration MessagingTemplate thread safe?

Tags: multithreading, performance, spring-integration

In my Singleton class I use [MessagingTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/core/MessagingTemplate.html) for sending messages to channel. Currently, I create the instance of [MessagingTemplate](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/api/org/springframework/integration/core/MessagingTemplate.html) each time I need to send a message. I wonder a) how expensive this operation, b) is it thread safe object, so I can initialise it once and use it in multithreaded environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not expensive to create, but it's unnecessary. The template is thread-safe. This is true for all the framework components.

Comment: Thanks Gary! Can I ask also what is the difference between MessagingTemplate#send vs MessagingChannel#send ?

Comment: The template is an abstraction over the channel - as well as `send`, it provides additional functionality like `convertAndSend`, `sendAndReceive` etc.